# How to save the document template using OpenXML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I need to replace the value and save the template document using OpenXML. I replace the value but template document cannot be opened.

My code is:

```
private void SavePart(OpenXmlPart part, string text)
{
   using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(part.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
   {
      sw.Write(text);
   }
}
```

I need to open the that "part" document.

Comment: Can you also post the code where you're reading the document? This only has the write operation.

Comment: Also what type of file are you attempting to edit? OpenXML is used for reading/writing Word Processing Documents, Spreadsheets, etc. and the methods of properly reading/writing can vary slightly depending on the document you're working with.

Comment: Can you please explain to me why you're using an `IDictionary` to store the contents? From what I see I think you may be over complicating the process. At my job I implemented a tagging system to replace tags in a docx file with data from SQL and I didn't have to do anything near that complicated.

Comment: We need the code, the error trace and line where it occurs.